# FragmetnActivity and ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I want to add action bar button to my FramgentActivity. I tried to follow the action bar article here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

But my activity inherits `FragmentActivity` and I cannot change that to `ActionBarActivity`. What should I do?

**EDIT:**
Starting from android API 11 action bar is built-in feature in Activity class so when I inherited `FragmentActivity` I had it. All I had to do is to override these two functions:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
} 

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: why cant you change to ActionBarActivity? It derives from fragmentActivity so I see no problem technically.

Comment: because I am using android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Comment: ActionBarActivity is derived from different FragmentActivity I believe

Comment: ActionBarActivity is derived from FragmentActivity of the support.v4 package but is provided in the v7 package of the support library. There are no 2 FragmentActivity. To use ActionBarActivity in older version just add android support v7 library (its a library project unlike support-v4.jar)

Comment: it seems I misunderstood it, I will give it a try